# Four div areas not loading at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I am building a website on wordpress, where it has four div areas (please check the first image), and contents are:

1. AREA-1: it's loading plain text content directly from html codes.
2. AREA-2: it loads 4 posts with thumbnail images from category-1, and showing as a slider.
3. AREA-3: it also loads 4 posts with thumbnail images, but from category-2, and showing as a slider.
4. AREA-4: it loads a contact form with 4 fileds using Contact Form-7 plugin.

[image: this is after the page fully loads]

Now the problem is, while the page is loading, AREA-1 and AREA-4 loads fast and visible without AREA-3 and AREA-4, which looks much odd. This is how it looks like while the page is loading (following image):

[image: this is how it looks like when page is loading]

How can I fix this problem please? I want to load them all-together.
There is a large image slider (on top) with four images on the page as well. So using onload event for area-1 and area-4 will cause area-2 and area-3 load faster. And if I use onload for all the areas, then page will remain empty, while all the slider images will load. They are much large image, and it will not look good.
So is there any way to load all the 4 areas to load at the same time, doesn't matter if the image slider (on top) is fully loaded or not? I am not much good with javascript. So any help will be really appreciating.

Comment: Set 1st and 4th to hidden and then show them again in onload event

Comment: it's more of a design issue.. talk to your designer. I would suggest have a box with loading animation for Area 2 and 3, and render content once it arrives

Comment: @Igle there is a large slider with 4 images. Using onload will make area-2 and 3 to load faster than area-1 and 4. And if I use onload for all the areas, page will be empty while slider images are loading. I want all four areas to be loaded at the same time, doesn't matter if the image slider is loaded yet or not. Any idea for this?

Comment: @Ravi Hamsa Website owner doesn't want the loading animation.

Comment: just put a placeholder box

Answer (score 0):

2 Options:

1. preload the images http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/
2. hide the text areas until the onload event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

Comment: there is a large slider with 4 images. Using onload will make area-2 and 3 to load faster than area-1 and 4. And if I use onload for all the areas, page will be empty while slider images are loading. I want all four areas to be loaded at the same time, doesn't matter if the image slider is loaded yet or not. Any idea for this?